# Trying to coerce the data onto a Gaussian curve and the results are not as expected

Tags: r, statistics

this is not a question about curve fitting. Instead, what I have is a collection of 60 different sites, from which I can collect maximum, minimum and average temperatures. I need to be able to use this data to calculate the operating temperature of a photovoltaic cell; it doesn't make sense to do this, however, with the average temperatures because it includes values from after sunset. Instead, I first create a "fake" average temperature (this is our "fake average", `totalityoftemperatures_fakemeans`) which is the average value of the maximum and minimum temperatures. At that point, I calculate an adjusted minimum temperature by subtracting one standard deviation (assuming 6 * sd = max - min), and then finally calculate an "adjusted" mean temperature which is the average of the new minimum (fake mean - 1 * sd) and the pre-existing maximum temperature (so this is our "adjusted mean").

What really bothers me is that this re-calculated average ought to be higher than the "fake" mean; after all, it is an average value of the adjusted minimum together with the original maximum value. I might also cross-post this to the statistics stack exchange or something, but I'm pretty sure that this is a coding issue right now. Is there anyone out there who can look at the below code in R?

```
#The first data sets of maxima and minima are taken from empirical data 

for(i in 1:nrow(totalityofsites))
{
  for(j in 1:12)
  {
    totalityoftemperatures_fakemeans[i,j] = mean(totalityoftemperatures_maxima[i,j], totalityoftemperatures_minima[i,j])
  }
}  

totality_onesigmaDF = abs((1/6)*(totalityoftemperatures_maxima - totalityoftemperatures_minima))
totalityoftemperatures_adjustedminima = totalityoftemperatures_fakemeans - totality_onesigmaDF


for(i in 1:nrow(totalityofsites))
{
  for(j in 1:12)
  {
  totalityoftemperatures_adjustedmeans[i,j] = mean(totalityoftemperatures_adjustedminima[i,j], totalityoftemperatures_maxima[i,j])
  }

}

#The second calculation of the average should be higher than "fake" but that is not the case
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem lies in your use of the `mean` function. When you do this:

```r
mean(totalityoftemperatures_adjustedminima[i,j], totalityoftemperatures_maxima[i,j])
```

You are calling mean with two arguments. The function only takes one argument, a vector of numbers. If you supply it with two numbers it will ignore the second one. Look:

```
mean(2, 100)
#[1] 2
```

Whereas if you concatenate the values into a single vector, you get the right answer:

```r
mean(c(2, 100))
#[1] 51
```

So you need to change

```r
mean(totalityoftemperatures_maxima[i,j], totalityoftemperatures_minima[i,j])
```

to

```
mean(c(totalityoftemperatures_maxima[i,j], totalityoftemperatures_minima[i,j]))
```

and

```
mean(totalityoftemperatures_adjustedminima[i,j], totalityoftemperatures_maxima[i,j])
```

to

```
mean(c(totalityoftemperatures_adjustedminima[i,j], totalityoftemperatures_maxima[i,j]))
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I really ought to have known this. Embarrassed and grateful in equal measure!